# which winJS event handler should be used while minimizing an application on windows 8?

Tags: cordova, winjs

I am working on a cordova application. I have to close the camera window when app is minimized or suspended.
I have tried using pause and resume events but they do not trigger on minimizing the app.

I have also tried the following:

```
**WinJS.Application.addEventListener("onactivated", function () {
               var cameraElement = document.getElementById("scanWindow");
               cameraElement.style.display = 'none';
               cameraElement.parentNode.removeChild(cameraElement);
           }, false);**
```

And

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
document.getElementById("scanWindow").addEventlistener("pause", onCamPause, false);
}, false);

function onCamPause() {
                   var cameraElement = document.getElementById("scanWindow");
                   cameraElement.style.display = 'none';
                   cameraElement.parentNode.removeChild(cameraElement);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handled it with msvisibilitychange event and it works fine. I can close the camera window here for when we are minimizing the application

Comment: Are there any ways to minimize windows cordova apps programmatically?